# wildfly Failed to resolve expression

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, java-ee-8

I'm trying to launch a Java Web Project with Eclipse and Wildfly. When I try to run the wildfly server I recieve the following issue:

> Failed to resolve expression: entornoDT

But this variable was added in "Wildfly Launch configuration properties" > "Environmet"

[Environmet variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWH4I.png)

It looks like the project doesn't take the profile correctly. The error is because of this file: jboss-web.xml

In this line:

> `<context-root>kroneews${entornoDT}</context-root>`

Comment: entornoDT does not appear to have a value set.

Comment: No, but this is correct, I don't want it to have any value. Anyway, if I report a value it also returns the same error

Comment: As fas as i know, placeholders may be used in JBoss config files (ie "standalone-*.xml") but not in deployment descriptors